# Script to take long list of data and turn it into Scala lists?

Tags: python, bash, scala

I have a list of arcs(200lines max) in a graph like shown below. The triple is (x, y, z) which means an edge from x to y at weight z. I know exactly how many lines are in the file(number of edges), the number of nodes too. I want to create an adjacency matrix input with these edges in Scala using List from Scala. Syntax is like i.e for example`List(List(0,0,0,0), List(0,0,0,0)))` I want to have a script that can take in a .txt file of the form shown below and output Scala syntax of an adj. list from these edges.

`LIST OF ARCS
0   1   0.440004
0   2   0.244452
0   3   0.433273`

For the input above, the output should be

`ListBuffer(
      ListBuffer(0, 0.440004, 0.244452, 0.433273),
      ListBuffer(0.440004, 0, 0, 0),
      ListBuffer(0.244452, 0, 0, 0),
      ListBuffer(0.433273, 0, 0, 0))`

Here is what I have and my idea. 
val lines = Source.fromFile("f1.txt").getLines.toList.map(i => println(i))
I can prefill a ListBuffer.fill(10)(10) and then if I can figure out how to make each line a triple of type Ints, then I can update the ListBuffer structure I prefilled.

Comment: Why is this tagged with Python?

Comment: I am interested in a Script, and python scripting is often used for this purpose.

Comment: So what's the expected output for that list?

Comment: So how long list is _very, very long_? Millions? Billions?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stuck at some point? Here's a good start: http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-open-read-text-files-in-scala-cookbook-examples

Comment: What's the expected output if there are for example 5 arcs instead of 3?

Comment: @JamesBrown The number of rows, is dependent on the number of nodes, which is given, I do have that to begin with.

Comment: @TeodoricoLevoff If you want to have a Scala structure as result, python and bash are not relevant tags and actually misleading.

Comment: @maasg It actually isn't because the task can be completed with bash or Python. The solution provided by Alex Hall is in Python shown below.

Comment: What happens to second output row `ListBuffer(0, 0.440004, 0.244452, 0.433273),` if the amount of arcs grows? Are all the weights listed in it?

Comment: @JamesBrown Yes they are.

Comment: @TeodoricoLevoff it's kind of absurd to use another (scripting) language to generate scala code for a simple task like this. Note how the script in the answer generates text, not a Scala list like asked in the question.

Comment: @TeodoricoLevoff I added the scala version for the sake of future visitors. Note how going through a text-wrangling script is not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open('input.txt') as infile:
    lines = infile.readlines()[1:]  # skip header
edges = [line.split() for line in lines]
edges = [(int(t[0]), int(t[1]), float(t[2])) for t in edges]
n = max(max(edge[:2]) for edge in edges) + 1
matrix = [[0] * n for _ in range(n)]
for edge in edges:
    for x, y in [edge[:2], reversed(edge[:2])]:
        matrix[x][y] = edge[2]

print(str(matrix).replace('[', 'ListBuffer(').replace(']', ')'))
```

Answer (score 2):

In awk:

```
$ cat program.awk
NR>1 {
    a[NR]=$3
    nr=NR
}
END {
    lb="ListBuffer("
    a[1]=0
    for(i=0;i<=nr;i++) {
        b[i]=(i>0?"\t":"") lb (i>1?a[i]:"")
        b[1]=b[1] a[i] (i<nr?",":"")
    }
    for(i=0;i<=nr;i++)
        printf "%s%s%s\n", b[i], (i>1?",0,0,0":""), (i>0?")"(i<nr?",":")"):"")
}
```

Run it:

```
$ awk -f program.awk f1.txt
ListBuffer(
        ListBuffer(0,0.440004,0.244452,0.433273),
        ListBuffer(0.440004,0,0,0),
        ListBuffer(0.244452,0,0,0),
        ListBuffer(0.433273,0,0,0))
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to try to generate Scala source code with a script when we can directly create the desired structure by reading the file and processing its inputs in Scala.

Given the following "arcs.txt" file:

```
LIST OF ARCS
0   1   0.440004
0   2   0.244452
0   3   0.433273
1   3   0.161616
```

We read the data and make it into a list

```
import scala.io.Source
val arcData = Source.fromFile("/home/maasg/playground/data/arcs.txt").getLines.toList
```

Drop the header, parse the text and preserve well formed data points as a `Map` of `(x,y)-> weight`. Note that this is already a sparse matrix representation where absent values can be assumed to be 0.

```
val sparse = arcData.drop(1)
                  .flatMap{line =>  line.split("[ ]+") match {
                                        case Array(from, to, weight.toDouble) => Some(((from, to), weight))
                                        case _ => None
                                     }
                           }
                  .toMap
```

To obtain a dense matrix, we first calculate the vertices using the keys of the sparse matrix:

```
val vertices = sparse.keys.flatMap{case (v1, v2) => Seq(v1,v2)}.toList
```

Then, we create a dense adjacency matrix representation:

```
val matrix = vertices.map(xs => vertices.map(ys => sparse.get((xs,ys)).getOrElse(0.0)))
// matrix: List[List[Double]] = List(List(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
//     List(0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.161616), 
//     List(0.0, 0.440004, 0.0, 0.244452, 0.433273), 
//     List(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), 
//     List(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
//)
```